# Await a custom event in Typsescript before continuing

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, events

I have a function:

```
async ready():Promise<boolean> {
    await this.myClass.firstToComplete();
    this.myClass.secondToComplete();
}
```

But `firstToComplete()` needs to wait for an event it is listening for before it can continue.

```
async firstToComplete(): Promise<void>{
   return new Promise(resolve =>  this.anEventListener = () => resolve());
}
```

But I'm not certain how to structure this correctly.

Here's a summary of my current codebase:

```
async ready():Promise<boolean> {
             await this.myClass.firstToComplete();
             this.myClass.secondToComplete();
         }

export class myClass{
    private static completion_event = new Event("complete");

    async anEventListener(): Promise<void>{
        await window.addEventListener("complete", function(){
            return
        });
    }

    async firstToComplete(): Promise<void> {
         await this.listening();


    async listening() {
        return new Promise(resolve =>  this.anEventListener = () => resolve());
    }

    private static functionWaitingToComplete() {
        window.dispatchEvent(this.completion_event)
    }
```

Comment: You might want to look into Promise.all() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with events and promises, but the way I see it, there are two options to go about it, one is to resolve the promise inside the event, the other is passing the the second function as callback

The first option would go something like this:

```js
const firstFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const onMyEvent= () => {
      resolve("Event occured");
    };

    window.addEventListener("eventName", onMyEvent);
  });
};

const secondFunction = () => {
  console.log("After first function event");
};

const asyncFunction = async () => {
  await firstFunction();
  secondFunction();
};
```

The second option would go like this:

```js
const firstFunction = (callback: () => void) => {
  const onMyEvent= () => {
    callback();
  };

  window.addEventListener("eventName", onMyEvent);
};

const secondFunction = () => {
  console.log("After first function event");
};

const mainFunction = () => {
  firstFunction(secondFunction);
};
```